# Updating and Compiling CSS Files in Xamarin

Tags: css, asp.net, xamarin, monodevelop

I've recently started using Xamarin/MonoDevelop as an alternative to Microsoft Visual Studio and my first project was to create a website using ASP.NET with MVC pattern. This has been going well, and I don't mind the extra code work, but I'm having a rough time with the CSS.

For whatever reason, any CSS file only seems to compile once, ignoring any changes I write to the file. From my research, this because content files are cached for the build.

Is there a method in Xamorin's files, Microsoft's aspnet and web packages, or Newtonsoft's or Razor's library? If so, in which part of my solution do I call it?

Is there an add-on to Xamarin? How do I use it?

Do I have to modify a config file?

Comment: From what I've read this is likely related to your browser caching the CSS, not necessarily the build caching the file. [See more information here.](https://forums.asp.net/t/1918561.aspx?CSS+not+refreshed)

Comment: Clearing the browser cache did work. Guess that means I need to write a quick re-versioning script. I just need to append a string beginning with '?' followed by my version number. Correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the issue was being caused by the browser cache not refreshing with changes to the build. The solution to this is to append a version to the end of the path name for the stylesheet. Since I am using cshtml, I decided to use this:

```
<head>
    @{
        string version = "?v=2";
        string stylePathSite = "../../Content/Styles/SiteStyles.css" + 
            version;
        string stylePathNav = "../../Content/Styles/NavBarStyles.css" + 
            version;
    }
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="@stylePathSite"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="@stylePathNav"/>
</head>
```

I can later write a controller to be update the version variable from my model. Hope any fellow newbies out there find this helpful.